# CoffeeScript: No output after installation

Tags: coffeescript, installation, ubuntu-13.04

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, after installing using:

```
$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

..with output..

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/bin/cake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
coffee-script@1.6.3 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
```

No commands yields any result, whatsoever:

```
$ coffee js.coffee 
$ coffee -v
$ coffee GiveMeSomeCoffeePlease
```

I verified that it exists:

```
$ which coffee 
/usr/local/bin/coffee
```

And the file has some contents:

```
$ cat `which coffee`
#!/usr/bin/env node

var path = require('path');
var fs   = require('fs');
var lib  = path.join(path.dirname(fs.realpathSync(__filename)), '../lib');

require(lib + '/coffee-script/command').run();
```

Also tried version 1.6.1 which works on my laptop. No difference on this computer though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I had installed the package `node` on Ubuntu, which is something entirely different:

> Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)  The
>   existing node package has been renamed to ax25-node. This transitional
>   package exists to ease the upgrade path for existing users.

I went ahead and installed the `nodejs` package. But seems it didn't quite create the right binding anyway, I could run `nodejs` but not `node`. So I made an alias for it and now CoffeeScript is running just fine!

`cd /usr/bin; sudo ln -s nodejs node`

Comment: [Still true](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/node) on Ubuntu 14.10. So I removed package `node` with `sudo apt-get purge node && sudo apt-get autoremove`, then installed the right stuff with `sudo apt-get install nodejs`, then the link with `cd /usr/local/bin; sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs node`. (You switched your `ln` arguments accidentally.)

Comment: Yeah it's strange nobody's changed this so far, bet it's not an unusual mistake. I've edited my post to change order for the symbolic link creation, thanks.

Comment: Happens to me all. the. time. The least intuitive part of Linux. :P

Answer (score 0):

Same here .. In my expressjs app, instead of running via

```
node app
```

now it seems I have to run it via

```
nodejs app
```

I ll either create an alias or a symlink like Mika did. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 fyi.